# как нарисовать кости поверх фигуры? opengl es2.0

Tags: android-studio, opengl, шейдеры, gles2.0

требуется нарисовать фигуру и скелет внутри нее, НО так чтобы кости были видны и при этом фигура не прозрачна. То есть нарисовано как бы поверх. Как будто скелет рисуется в последнюю очередь.

Может как то можно управлять очередью рисования в  opengl es2.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй вот так.

```
loop(){
  -Включить тест глубины
  -Нарисуй фигуру
  -...(Другие вызовы отрисовки)
  -Отключить тест глубины
  -Нарисовать кости
}
```

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста какая команда управляет глубиной  в opengl es2.0 ? glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);  ?

Comment: Да именно она. И еще  команда для очистки буфера glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

Comment: спасибо Василий все получилось!  Успехов ВАМ.